# How to save configs in BrowserTestBase?

Tags: 8, configuration, testing

In a functional test I try to test a functionality after changing the module configuration:

```
public function setUp() {
  parent::setUp();
  ...
  $config = \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('move_file.settings');
  $config->set('vocabulary', 'tags');
  $config->save();
  ...
}
```

The tested functionality is located primarily in [MoveFileService.php](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/move_file/-/blob/8.x-1.x/src/Services/MoveFileService.php). But the service does not see the configs. When I debug the configs directly in the service, then I get:

```
public function __construct(ConfigFactory $config_factory, LoggerChannelFactoryInterface $logger_factory) {
    $this->config = $config_factory->get('move_file.settings');
    $this->logger = $logger_factory->get('move_file');
}

public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
    $container->get('config.factory'),
    $container->get('logger.factory')
    );
}

public function configsAreSet() {
    ...
    fwrite(STDOUT, "Settings: {$this->config->get('vocabulary')}\n");
    // Returns: Settings:
    // The configuration is null.

    $config = \Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable('move_file.settings');
    fwrite(STDOUT, "Settings: {$config->get('vocabulary')}\n");
    // Returns: Settings: tags
    // This returns the expected value. But the good practice is to use the dependency injection.
    ...
}
```

How can I save the config in the setUp() method of the functional test, so that the service can get the saved configuration, when the test is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found, that the problem was caused, that in the setUp() method of the test class, was at first used the $this->drupalCreateNode([...]) method and then were created the settings. **After moving the $config->set(...) method at the beginning of the setUp() method, works everything perfect.**

See:

- [The test class](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/move_file/-/blob/8.x-1.x/src/Tests/MoveFileComplexTest.php)
- [Test results](https://www.drupal.org/node/3115871/qa)